# How to fix linker errors for libudev on Ubuntu 15

Tags: c, linux, ld, udev, ubuntu-15.10

I've installed `libudev-dev`, I can see the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so` but when I run `gcc -Wall -ludev -o test test.c` I get following error..

```
opensourcegeek@box:~/project/udev_device_discovery$ gcc -Wall -ludev -o test test.c 
/tmp/ccg6Ydod.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `udev_new'
test.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new'
test.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem'
test.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_property'
test.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_property'
test.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
test.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry'
test.c:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name'
test.c:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath'
test.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent'
test.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode'
test.c:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x197): undefined reference to `udev_device_unref'
test.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next'
test.c:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref'
test.c:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `udev_unref'
test.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `udev_new'
test.c:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new'
test.c:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem'
test.c:(.text+0x225): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_property'
test.c:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_property'
test.c:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
test.c:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry'
test.c:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name'
test.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath'
test.c:(.text+0x297): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode'
test.c:(.text+0x2ba): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x2f4): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x308): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x32e): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
test.c:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to `udev_device_unref'
test.c:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next'
test.c:(.text+0x373): undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref'
test.c:(.text+0x37f): undefined reference to `udev_unref'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't usually run ubuntu, but same code works on my fedora(slightly older version of libudev) and also a pi which runs wheezy (older version of libudev).

Comment: gcc -Wall  test.c -ludev  try this or gcc --std=c99 test.c -ludev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order is important, put the library name at the end of the compilation / linking line:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o test test.c -ludev
```

Comment: Curious, how come fedora or wheezy is tolerant to the wrong order?

Comment: @opensourcegeek Either you had it in the right order on Fedora or you had it twice: `gcc -Wall -ludev -o test test.c -ludev` (or you had it as part of a Makefile?). Otherwise, GNU ld would have complained there too.

Comment: @l3x Doesn't look like it, I've tried it directly on command line `gcc -Wall -ludev -o test test.c` it works fine on fedora(gcc 4.8.2-7) and on wheezy(gcc 4.6.3).

Answer (score 2):

The error you see is a linker error, not because of any installation issues.. Move `-ludev` to the *end* of the command line option:

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c -ludev
```